# Dataframe between function showing incorrect results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wanting to print those rows where `item_pricefinal` is between `item_price1` and `item_price2`

Here the code and dataset I'm running -

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # Number of columns to be displayed
pd.set_option('display.width', None)  # Max table width to display
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # Max number of rows
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)  # Turn off SettingWithCopyWarning warning

data_list = <<Please read from here - https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aiw4HhkSppuhET8gSypP?e=y71rot
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
data_df.columns = ['item_date', 'item_price1', 'item_price2', 'item_pricefinal', 'itempricefinal-itemprice1', 'itempricefinal-itemprice2']
mask = data_df['item_pricefinal'].between(data_df['item_price1'], data_df['item_price2'])
```

The output is false for every single row although there are rows where this condition holds good.

Example - In the following entry 0.890624368082415 is between 0.90588 & 0.86638 but the `between` function thinks it isn't and prints false in the output

```
['2020-03-09 00:00:00', 0.90588, 0.86638, 0.8906243680824152, 152.55631917584833, 242.44368082415147]
```

Please could I request help to spot the error?

Comment: The first argument of `Series.between` takes the lower bound and second argument takes the upper bound. Its seems from your sample data that `itemprice1` is greater than `itemprice2` so in that case you have to reverse the order of passed arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `data_df['item_pricefinal'].between(a,b)` and `data_df['item_pricefinal'].between(b,a)`. The sequence (a,b) or (b,a) matters.

It seems `item_price2` is lower than `item_price1`. So the correct code should be

```
data_df['item_pricefinal'].between(data_df['item_price2'],data_df['item_price1'])
```

Answer (score 2):

In [pd.between(left, right)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html),  `left is left boundary` and `right is right boundary`

You example will work in this case

```
mask = data_df['item_pricefinal'].between(
    data_df['item_price2'], data_df['item_price1'])
```